Delphi Attribute / Custom Attribute
I have looked at some source code using Attributes / Custom Atributes
Is it possible to use it to define a property's value to conform to something like all Uppercase.
TMyObject = class
private
  MyName: string;
published
  [Uppercase]
  MyName: string read FMyName write FMyName;
end;

so instead of using a setter procedure SetMyName that sets FMyName to uppercase, is there a way to achieve always having MyName as uppercase through attributes?

UPDATE: I have tried this code. Please advise if this usage is fine. The problem is that IsPropertyUpperCase() never returns True. Did I do something wrong here?
TUpperCaseAttribute = class(TCustomAttribute)
private
  //
public
  constructor Create;
end;

TMyObject = class
private
  MyName: string;
published
  [Uppercase]
  MyName: string read FMyName write SetMyName;
end;

function IsPropertyUpperCase(aObject: TObject; aPropertyName: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;

  var Context: TRttiContext;
  var RType: TRttiType;
  var Prop: TRttiProperty;
  var LAttr: TCustomAttribute;

  Context := TRttiContext.Create;

  RType := Context.GetType(aObject.ClassType);
  // Code changed here to use the non-iterative method
  Prop := RType.GetProperty(aPropertyName);
  LAttr := Prop.GetAttribute<TUpperCaseAttribute>;
  if LAttr <> nil then
  begin
    Result := True;  
    showmessage(aPropertyName + ' is Uppercase!');
  end;

  // Iterate its properties, including the public ones.
  /*
  for Prop in RType.GetProperties do
  begin
    if CompareText(Prop.Name, aPropertyName) = 0 then
    begin
      for LAttr in Prop.GetAttributes() do
        if LAttr is TUpperCaseAttribute then
        begin
          Result := True;
          Break;
        end;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  */
  Context.Free;
end;

procedure TMyObject.SetMyName(aValue: string);
begin
  if aValue <> FMyName then
  begin
    { Check RTTI to see if property has "Uppercase" attribute }
    { Is it possible not to loop through each RTTI? }
    if IsPropertyUpperCase(self, 'MyName') then
      FMyName := UpperCase(AValue)
    else
      FMyName := AValue
  end;
end;


The update isn't going to make the code better than alternive approaches.

The attribute alone cannot do this. While attributes can have methods, these methods have to be called somewhere to be executed. Also the attribute has no way to know about neither the class nor the method, property or field it is used on.
Code can check if a property has the [Uppercase] attribute, but it has to act appropriately itself.
As an example take the [Default] attribute declared in System.Classes. It allows to store a default value for some property that can be retrieved later, but it won't automatically initialize the property with this value.
Update:
So, you won't achieve your goal through attributes, but there is another approach using class operators:
type
  TUpperCaseString = record
  private
    FValue: string;
  public
    class operator Implicit(A: TUpperCaseString): string; overload;
    class operator Implicit(A: string): TUpperCaseString; overload;
  end;

class operator TUpperCaseString.Implicit(A: TUpperCaseString): string;
begin
  Result := A.FValue;
end;

class operator TUpperCaseString.Implicit(A: string): TUpperCaseString;
begin
  Result.FValue := A.ToUpper;
end;

Now, when you have a property or field of type TUpperCaseString, it will automatically return a string as upper case even when assigned a lower case one.

thanks Uwe! How does the code check if the property has the [Uppercase] attribute?  or can I give it a random attribute 'ucase'?  (given in this case, ucase is not a function, so how do I check a property has 'ucase' attribute?

@Peter Jones attributes are documented and that documentation tells you the answer to all of your questions

The examples I saw are more complicated involving functions. What I need is a simple declaration-type instead of function-type of attribute.

You don't get to decide how the feature works. You get to use what you are given. Attributes are classes. You can then extract them at run time using RTTI. as documented. Attributes are indeed declarative for the user, but the code behind that implements behaviour based on those declarations, you have to provide.

I have updated the code. Please advise if this usage is fine. problem is that the IsPropertyUpperCase(..) never returns a True.

@UweRaabe Re your TUpperCaseString approach - does it work for published properties? I don't think the Object Inspector will understand that type.

@RemyLebeau Of course one needs to register a suitable property editor for that type.

Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/UweRaabe/f701ff66dcc23b03dd8a9294fdf148ba

@UweRaabe Upvoted your answer although I can't use this for current issue, but it will come in handy at some point. Nice workaround!

Not the way you are looking for, no.
Attributes are just extra RTTI data, nothing more. Per the documentation:
Attributes and RTTI

Attributes are a language feature in Delphi that allows annotating types and type members with special objects that carry additional information. This information can be queried at run time...
Attributes do not modify the behavior of types or members by themselves. The consumer code must specifically query for their existence and take appropriate actions when this is required.

For instance, if you were writing your own code that reads/writes property values based on RTTI, then you could certainly implement a custom attribute to handle this.
But, there is no functionality in the native RTL that will automatically force a property value to uppercase based on such an attribute.

I have edited the post to include some sample code. However, IsPropertyUpperCase(..) does not return a True for 'MyName'. Did I do something wrong here?

You can remove the loops in your function by using TRttiType.GetProperty() and TRttiProperty.GetAttribute()

Do your have RTTI enabled in your project? IE, no {$RTTI EXPLICIT PROPERTIES[]} directive, etc?

Thanks for the above tips.  No, I do not have this RTTI directive.  The RTTI works in the sense I am able to loop through properties and attributes, just that the IsPropertyUpperCase() never returns True.  If I can just get IsPropertyUpperCase() to work, then I believe this solution will work?

Did you try to actually debug the code line by line to see where it is failing to behave as expected?

Yes, I did. the code runs ok but it never gets to the point where the function returns true and break, so means the code didn't find a property that has this attribute.

whether I use the loops, or GetProperty() and GetAttribute() as you suggested, both never get to return True.

You missed the point of my suggestion. WHICH OPERATION is not behaving as expected? Does GetProperties() not return an array containing your property? Does GetProperty() not find your property? Does GetAttributes() not return an array containing your attribute? Does GetAttribute() not find your attribute? Does the is operator not find a matching class? Please be more specific.

the GetAttribute always returns a NIL.  the GetProperty can find the property. so there was nothing I could find in the loop.  I found the problem.  Delphi doesn't flag during compilation if the attributes in [.....] does not match anything.  It should be [TUppercase] not [Uppercase].  Thanks for the input and help.

Then simply drop the T from the class name: TUpperCaseAttribute -> UpperCaseAttribute, so the compiler will accept [UpperCase]. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_Custom_Attributes_(RTTI)#Attribute_Names_that_End_with_.27Attribute.27_are_Implicitly_Shortened

Changing it to Uppercase confuses the compiler when I have other code that uses Uppercase(), and as it will be too much work to convert all the older code to .ToUpper, TUppercase is good enough. Thanks so much for your input.

What could it be confused about? The shortening only happens on attribute classes, and functions like SysUtils.UpperCase() can't be confused for attributes. Can you provide an example? Sounds like something that should probably be reported as a bug

Any Uppercase() function usage that is not used as SysUtils.UpperCase() is flagged by the compiler.
